# Form is not updating when using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using React Hooks my inputs are not updating. It means that when I'm updating the input in HTML, the `formData` is like:
`{username: "", password: "", "": "a", undefined: undefined}`. What's happening?

```
export default function Login() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const body = {
      username: (event.currentTarget as any).username.value,
      password: (event.currentTarget as any).password.value,
    };

    const res = await fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      Router.push("/");
    }
  }

  function handleChange(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [event.currentTarget?.name]: event.currentTarget?.value,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          label="User name"
          placeholder="Enter your username"
          type="text"
          value={formData.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <FormInput
          label="Password"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
          type="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

        <Link href="/register">Create account</Link>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

FormInput component is just:

```
type Props = {
  label: string;
} & React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>;

export default function FormInput({ label, ...props }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={label}>{label}</label>
      <input {...props} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `handleChange` as a callback and add the `name` prop. Use `event.target`;

```
export default function Login() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const body = {
      username: (event.currentTarget as any).username.value,
      password: (event.currentTarget as any).password.value,
    };

    const res = await fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      Router.push("/");
    }
  }

  const handleChange(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [event.target?.name]: event.target?.value,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          label="User name"
          placeholder="Enter your username"
          type="text"
          value={formData.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="username"
        />

        <FormInput
          label="Password"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
          type="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="password"
        />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

        <Link href="/register">Create account</Link>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that's not the problem. It's still not working.

Comment: @Cholewka you need to also add the ``name`` prop to ``FormInput`` since you reference it in ``event``

Comment: Still not updating

Comment: @Cholewka i update dmy answer, can you try and check? I added the name prop to FormInput

Comment: @Cholewka you should use event.target

Comment: It works now! Strangely, the types from React said that the `event.target` only has event methods like `addEventListener`. Thank you. :)